# What would make my ac unit hiss

Tags: hvac

I live in a mobile home and my central ac unit starting hissing pretty loud 3 days ago and tday it is blowing only warm air. There is no water or ice inside or out. The outside unit is running but it does sound a little odd but can't describe the noise. The outside don't look dirty but we have not cleaned it this year yet so I know it could be. But is there anything else that could be a problem

Comment: Was there a cloud of fog maybe freon leak? If so don't run it call a HVAC company if your system sprung a leak it may be able to be sealed pulled back to a vacuum and recharged

Comment: No cloud of fog and we cleaned inside and out with cleaner and it's running now but only runs cold for couple hrs then we have to shut it off for a bit then it runs fine again so I don't know

Comment: Please provide a make and model.  Do you know if it is a heat pump.

Answer (score 1):

Call a local HVAC company, it sounds like a refrigerant leak.  Don't run the system until somebody has looked at it, as you could damage the compressor and/or other components.

Comment: We cleaned the evaporator inside real good and then the coils outside. It ran cold for couple hrs and the noise stopped then started getting warm again and the hissing started again. We shut it off then turned it back on this morning and it done same thing.

Comment: If it was a refrigerant leak would it be able to cool at all?

Answer (score 1):

Where *exactly* did you hear the noise from?

If it was coming from the lineset somewhere, that may be an 'easy' fix.

If it seemed to be coming from the inside coil or the condenser outside, that's a much more involved fix (basically, you'll have to replace that whole part), as I don't think any kind of "leak stopper" will suffice if you heard it blow (those are for small, slow leaks).

Either way, you probably need an A/C tech to come out. But you might want to skip that and go with a whole new system depending on the age of yours. IMO, any system that audibility pops a leak is probably done for.

You can run the fan to stir up some air in the meantime, but don't run the system anymore.